# Android App crashes after splashscreen

Tags: android

I am creating an app which right now is really basic and only has a splash screen going into a blank screen. for some reason the application crashes straight after the splash screen when trying to load up the second screen. this has worked before so I'm unsure if its the second screen which worked but i have not changed ot the end to the splash screen.

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
protected boolean active = true;
protected int splashtime = 5000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, FullscreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        }, splashtime);



}
```

i think the problem is trying to pass through to the second class. the code for the second class is

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    }
}
```

unsure what the problem is but it's likely i'm just missing something really simple

Logcat:

```
    01-15 20:41:25.120: D/AndroidRuntime(411): Shutting down VM
01-15 20:41:25.120: W/dalvikvm(411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.timestables/com.example.timestables.FullscreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.example.timestables.Splashscreen$1.run(Splashscreen.java:27)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-15 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 20:41:29.069: I/Process(411): Sending signal. PID: 411 SIG: 9
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.timestables.Splashscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.FullscreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: PROTIP: If your app is crashing, always post your LogCat

Comment: post your LOGcat. Probably you haven't declared your activity in manifest..

Comment: `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.timestables/com.example.timestables.FullscreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're declaring the activity in your Manifest is wrong (the package is different then the one your activity is in).

change

```
android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.FullscreenActivity"
```

to

```
android:name="com.example.timestables.FullscreenActivity"
```

It even asks you if you declared it in your Manifest.

Comment: Yeah i feel so stupid now. it's been a while since i coded in android and just forgot that. using old code to create a new simple app

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest declares a different activity than the one you are starting:

```
 20:41:25.149: E/AndroidRuntime(411):
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
 activity class
 {com.example.timestables/com.example.timestables.FullscreenActivity};
 have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Look at the package and your imports. The activities are named the same, but the absolute path in the manifest must match the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in many android pojects. If the manifest file is correct then the main culprit in this type of splash app is the first intent mentioned in start intent line. Try changing it to some other activity and check if app still crashes after splash screen.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

change to some other activity like e.g. given here below

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
```